# Create a symbolic link (or other NTFS reparse point) in Windows Driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, ntfs

I can open, close, create files and directories using the `Zw*` functions available for Windows Kernel services. I can even open the underlying symbolic link object using `ZwOpenSymbolicLinkObject`, but I can't seem to actually make symbolic links.

It seems this level of the API is not aware of symbolic links, so how would I go about using this (filesystem!) feature without the Win32 API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't direct API to create reparse points.

You need to use  [`ZwFsControlFileZwFsControlFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to send [`FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ioctl with appropriate input buffers and parameters.

Don't have example though!

Comment: Ah, I thought as much. This will do nicely `:)`. Once I figure out how I need to call it...